# Vote Button is can't disable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning doing with JavaScript/HTML. I have little bit problem with button, it can't disable after open or executed webpage and I don't want enter age at below 18 and store into array after click.

If age is over 18 then button is enable and click vote and then store into array.
Check code at below:

```js
// create an array
var myArr = [];
var VoteArry = [];

function pushData() {
  // get value from the input text
  var Name = document.getElementById('fName').value;
  var Surname = document.getElementById('lName').value;
  var Age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  var Country = document.getElementById('countryID').value;
  var Vote = document.getElementById('voteID').value;

  // Merge all values of user information into Array
  var inputText = "Vote Database:" + "<br/>" + Name + " " + Surname + "<br/>" + Age + "<br/>" + Country + "<br/>" + Vote;


  //age verification

  var ageEl = document.getElementById('age');

  manageBtn(ageEl);

  ageEl.addEventListener('input', function() {
    manageBtn(ageEl);
  });

  function manageBtn(el) {
    var age = ageEl.value;
    if (age < 18) {
      document.getElementById('age').style.borderColor = '#e52213';
      document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('age').style.borderColor = '';
      document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;
    }
  }

  // send data to the array
  myArr.push(inputText);
  VoteArry.push(Vote)
  var pval = "";
  var pvote = "";

  //store count of how many peoples votes
  var countANC = 0;
  var countDA = 0;
  var countEFF = 0;

  //store the values into array with loop
  for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    pval = pval + myArr[i] + "<br/>";
    pvote = pvote + VoteArry[i];
  }

  // loop to check number of votes in parties
  for (i = 0; i < VoteArry.length; i++) {
    if ('ANC' == VoteArry[i]) {
      countANC++;
    }
    if ('DA' == VoteArry[i]) {
      countDA++;
    }
    if ('EFF' == VoteArry[i]) {
      countEFF++;
    }

  }
  // Display data from array
  document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
  document.getElementById('countANC').innerHTML = countANC;
  document.getElementById('countDA').innerHTML = countDA;
  document.getElementById('countEFF').innerHTML = countEFF;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  background-image: url("D:/Vote/lines.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}

#subBody {
  background-color: #E5E3E6;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 15px 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #aaaaaa
}

#VoteForm {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#VoteButton {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="subBody">
  <div id="VoteForm">
    <div>
      <h2>Election Day</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Personal Information:</h3>
      <label>Name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="fName" /><br/>
      <label>Surname</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="lName" /><br/>
      <label>Age</label><br/>
      <input type="number" id="age">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Nationality:</h3>
      <label for="country">Choose a country:</label><br/><br/>
      <select name="country" id="countryID">
        <option value="South African">South African</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwean">Zimbabwean</option>
        <option value="Namibian">Namibian</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>

    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Choose to vote:</h3>
      <label for="vote">Choose one of any party to vote:</label><br/><br/>
      <select name="votes" id="voteID">
        <option value="ANC">ANC</option>
        <option value="DA">DA</option>
        <option value="EFF">EFF</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="VoteButton"><button id="Btn" onclick="pushData();">Vote</button></div>
    <div>
      <label>ANC:</label>
      <p id="countANC"></p>
      <label>DA:</label>
      <p id="countDA"></p>
      <label>EFF:</label>
      <p id="countEFF"></p>
    </div>
    <p id="pText"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if(Age<18) return;` ?

Answer (score 0):

You were adding the `eventListener` on the age `input` inside `pushData`. That is why you needed to submit your form once.

```js
// create an array
var myArr = [];
var VoteArry = [];

//age verification

  var ageEl = document.getElementById('age');

  ageEl.addEventListener('input', function() {
    manageBtn(ageEl);
  });

  function manageBtn(el) {
    var age = ageEl.value;
    if (age < 18) {
      document.getElementById('age').style.borderColor = '#e52213';
      document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('age').style.borderColor = '';
      document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;
    }
  }

function pushData() {
  // get value from the input text
  var Name = document.getElementById('fName').value;
  var Surname = document.getElementById('lName').value;
  var Age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  var Country = document.getElementById('countryID').value;
  var Vote = document.getElementById('voteID').value;

  // Merge all values of user information into Array
  var inputText = "Vote Database:" + "<br/>" + Name + " " + Surname + "<br/>" + Age + "<br/>" + Country + "<br/>" + Vote;  

  // send data to the array
  myArr.push(inputText);
  VoteArry.push(Vote)
  var pval = "";
  var pvote = "";

  //store count of how many peoples votes
  var countANC = 0;
  var countDA = 0;
  var countEFF = 0;

  //store the values into array with loop
  for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    pval = pval + myArr[i] + "<br/>";
    pvote = pvote + VoteArry[i];
  }

  // loop to check number of votes in parties
  for (i = 0; i < VoteArry.length; i++) {
    if ('ANC' == VoteArry[i]) {
      countANC++;
    }
    if ('DA' == VoteArry[i]) {
      countDA++;
    }
    if ('EFF' == VoteArry[i]) {
      countEFF++;
    }

  }
  // Display data from array
  document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
  document.getElementById('countANC').innerHTML = countANC;
  document.getElementById('countDA').innerHTML = countDA;
  document.getElementById('countEFF').innerHTML = countEFF;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  background-image: url("D:/Vote/lines.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}

#subBody {
  background-color: #E5E3E6;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 15px 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #aaaaaa
}

#VoteForm {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#VoteButton {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="subBody">
  <div id="VoteForm">
    <div>
      <h2>Election Day</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Personal Information:</h3>
      <label>Name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="fName" /><br/>
      <label>Surname</label><br/>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="lName" /><br/>
      <label>Age</label><br/>
      <input type="number" id="age">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Nationality:</h3>
      <label for="country">Choose a country:</label><br/><br/>
      <select name="country" id="countryID">
        <option value="South African">South African</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwean">Zimbabwean</option>
        <option value="Namibian">Namibian</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>

    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Choose to vote:</h3>
      <label for="vote">Choose one of any party to vote:</label><br/><br/>
      <select name="votes" id="voteID">
        <option value="ANC">ANC</option>
        <option value="DA">DA</option>
        <option value="EFF">EFF</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="VoteButton"><button id="Btn" onclick="pushData();">Vote</button></div>
    <div>
      <label>ANC:</label>
      <p id="countANC"></p>
      <label>DA:</label>
      <p id="countDA"></p>
      <label>EFF:</label>
      <p id="countEFF"></p>
    </div>
    <p id="pText"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```